# CSS conflict in backgrounds and border

Tags: html, css

Whilst designing a page i come across a conflict (i guess) in a div that holds a group of divs. 
How it currently looks http://castellvmaqvae.nl/exposities/
img is how it should look. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBmVF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following, your div inside the main div are wider than they should be, which in your case you want them the same width as the image, here is the updated CSS :

```
.col-md-4 third {
  width:25%; //You may want to play around with this on different screen sizes
}
```

OR FIXED WIDTH:

```
.col-md-4 third {
  width:200px; // Same width as the picture
}
```

Comment: For future it is a good idea to post the relevant code as @Paulie_D mentions to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just do this modify:

```
    `col-md-2` --> `col-md-1`

    `col-md-6` -->  `col-md-7 second` 

    `col-md-4 third` --> `col-md-3 third`
```

Also in the existing, add `text-align: center;` to `col-md-3 third`.

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you guys:
I was working on a wrapper to fit in the 3rd column and have a white background and border like this:
.verwikkeld {
 width:200px;
height:auto;
background-color:#FFF;
border:#999 1px solid;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:30px;
}
Could this be an option in some way, the positioning and the background are the main issues.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the wrappers background color has no effect but giving background color to the individual divs and borders seem to work great.
code:

```
.verwikkeld {width:316px;
height:auto;
background-color: #FFF;
border:#999 1px solid;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:30px;
}
.verwacht{color:#666;
border-left:#000 1px solid;
border-right:#000 1px solid;
border-top:#000 1px solid;
width:220px;
background-color:#FFF;
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
font-size:32px;
}
.verwacht_img{border-left:#000 1px solid;
border-right:#000 1px solid;
background-color:#FFF;
width:220px;
}
.verwacht_naam{color:#666;
border-left:#000 1px solid;
border-right:#000 1px solid;
background-color:#FFF;
width:220px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top:10px;
font-size:28px;
}
.verwacht_titel{color:#000;
border-left:#000 1px solid;
border-right:#000 1px solid;
background-color:#FFF;
width:220px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top:10px;
font-size:16px;
}
.verwacht_datum{color:#F90;
border-left:#000 1px solid;
border-right:#000 1px solid;
background-color:#FFF;
width:220px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top:10px;
font-size:12px;
}
.verwacht_text{color:#000;
border-left:#000 1px solid;
border-right:#000 1px solid;;
border-bottom:#000 1px solid;
background-color:#FFF;
width:220px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:20px;
font-size:12px;
}
```

Thank you guys for your time.